# Connect to a local service via VPN

Tags: networking, webserver, vpn

This may be a very obvious question to a lot of people on here. Unfortunately I'm PRETTY bad with networking, nuff said:

I have a local webservice running on PC A, that I can without a problem access (via the lan/the local ip address:port of PC A) from PC B.
What I'm trying now is to connect the same two PC's, while using the same VPN and being in two different physical networks.
My gut tells me, that I need to reconfigure the local webserver (PC A) to the (local) VPN address that got assigned to it, right? Reality is, this solution is not working. Any suggestions?

Cheers.